# Get Symfony2 general config values (not parameters!) in controller

Tags: symfony, configuration

How can I get values from `config.yml` or `security.yml` in the controller in Symfony2? I am not talking about the ones I define under "parameters" key (which one can easily get by `$this->container->getParameter()`), but those stored in upper levels.

For example, how can I get the `security.firewalls.my_firewall.remember_me.key` value?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the approach if you need custom parameters, but I need the values which I specify for the framework anyway - like the remember_me.key. What's the point in duplicating this value in the config?

Comment: You're right, I should do it this way. Thanks for your input, post it as an answer and I will accept it (+rep) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with defining a value as a parameter and assigning it to a value in `config.yml` or `security.yml`? You can easily get it from a controller then.

For example, add a parameter to the `parameters.ini` file:

```
remember_me_key = some_key_here
```

And then use it in the `security.yml` file:

```
security.firewalls.my_firewall.remember_me.key: %remember_me_key%
```

And access it from a controller the way you already do.

Comment: how do he access it from a controller "the way you already do"?